# Existence of Fredholm operator from $X$ to $Y$ implies $X \oplus \mathbb{C}^n$ isomorphic to $Y \oplus \mathbb{C}^m$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces over, say $\mathbb{C}$, and let $T : X \to Y$ be a Fredholm operator (that is, $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is closed, with $\ker(T)$ and $Y/\mathrm{Im}(T)$ finite-dimensional).

> I would like to show that there exists some integers $m, n \geq 0$ so that $$X \oplus \mathbb{C}^n \simeq Y \oplus \mathbb{C}^m, $$ in the sense that there exists some bounded linear map $X \oplus \mathbb{C}^n \to Y \oplus \mathbb{C}^m$ which is invertible.

I do not know how to prove this. I assume that $n$ and $m$ would be equal to the dimensions of $\ker(T)$ and $Y/\mathrm{Im}(T)$, but I am not exactly sure how to define a bijective linear map $$Y \oplus \ker(T) \to X \oplus (Y/\mathrm{Im}(T)). $$ A "naive map" could be $$(y, x) \mapsto (x, \pi(y)), $$ where $\pi : Y \to Y/\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is the projection, which is continuous and linear, but I cannot prove that it is injective. In any case, this is certainly not surjective.

Comment: First, why are you trying to map backwards? Can you give a projection $X\to\ker(T)$ and a splitting $Y/\text{Im}(T) \to Y$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I can for the first one, but I am not sure what you mean by the second one. Since $\ker(T)$ and $Y/\mathrm{Im}(T)$ are finite-dimensional, both $\ker(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ are topologically complemented. But how can I use this?

Comment: Well, then you have an obvious map $X\oplus Z\to Y\oplus \ker(T)$, where $Z\subset Y$ is isomorphic to $Y/\text{Im}(T)$ and projects isomorphically thereto.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry but it is not obvious to me. I am not completely sure how the map could be defined; to what is the element in $Z$ mapped to? I assume that the map would look something like $$(x, z) \mapsto (..., \pi(x)), $$ where $\pi : X \to \ker(T)$ is the projection mentioned before.

Comment: Sure. How 'bout $T(x)+z$ for the first coordinate?

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed, this map works, and I checked that it is indeed bijective! Thank you! Could you please post your comment as a solution so I can accept the answer and close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $T$ is Fredholm, we know $\ker T$ is finite-dimensional and so (say, by Hahn-Banach) we can define a continuous projection $\pi\colon X\to\ker T$. Similarly, because $T$ is Fredholm, $Y/\text{Im}(T)$ is finite-dimensional and we can choose a continuous mapping $\sigma\colon Y/\text{Im}(T)\to Y$ so that $\sigma$ followed by the projection is the identity. Let $Z=\text{Im}(\sigma)$.

We now define $\psi\colon X\oplus Z \to Y\oplus\ker(T)$ by
$$\psi(x,z) = (T(x)+z,\pi(x)).$$
You can easily check that $\psi$ is continuous, surjective, and injective.